# specific bone wont move but other will

Tags: modifiers, bones, transforms, pose-mode, inverse-kinematics

I'm trying to get one bone to move outward (left arm bone) but it won't move. the other one moves just fine and they (as far as I can see) have the same constraints. below is the blend file along with the image specifying my problem. please let me know if you need any more information

[blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uDDcRuJhSWhoTuTmGarPA32R9bC5aNvr/view?usp=sharing)

[image: defined bones]

Comment: I don't have time to dig for it right now, but you definitely have a dependency loop on the IK chain for the left arm.  If you move the IK controller everything moves more than it should.  Go over the chain carefully and look for improper parenting.

Comment: been searching for any improper parenting for a bit now and the left side matches the parenting on the right side (to the respected right/left bones)

Comment: so i unparented every bone in the left arm and deleted all child of constraints in the left arm and even deleted the IK constraint but it still wont move

Answer (score 0):

the way that this got past me and wasn't my immediate thought is absolutely beyond me. the thing is I had all transform options locked... really hope this helps someone not go through what I did